# Does the Facebook API for iOS leak?

Tags: iphone, facebook, memory-leaks, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

When testing a demo app in Instruments using the leaks tool, I get GeneralBlock-XXXX that can be 56 or 2048. This happens after selecting the Publish button. (which actually calls [Facebook dialog:@"feed"];)

Can anyone confirm this? Does this have anything to do with UIWebView?

BTW, it is reproduced only on device (I used iPhone4) and not in Simulator. There are more reports on this like: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/issues/309

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This looks like its an issue with UIWebView, and is fairly well known from different situations.  I can't possibly summarize all the suggested answers, so I think you should look at the following two SO questions which address people having this issue:

[generalblock-56-memory-leak-when-calling-loadrequest-in-uiwebview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5470121/generalblock-56-memory-leak-when-calling-loadrequest-in-uiwebview)

[general-block-56-1024-8-244-24-memory-leaks-using-uiwebview-loadrequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739696/general-block-56-1024-8-244-24-memory-leaks-using-uiwebview-loadrequest)

Comment: Thanks Ian. I know there were issues with UIWebView in the past but I was quite sure that Apple fixed them all by now. Kind of petty we need to deal with such basic stuff. Thanks for the links anyway!